# Не могу получить значение аннотации у класса

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Итак есть аннотация `@MyAnno`

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnno {
    String value();
}
```

Почему я не могу получить доступ к ее значению через код `clazz.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class)` с помощью метода `value()`,где `Class clazz = object.getClass();`

При работе с полями класса все ок, то есть этот код работает `field.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class).value()`, где `field` это элемент массива
`Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields()`

P.S `clazz.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnno.class)` выдает `true`

Comment: `object` приходит в качестве параметра в функцию: `Object object`

Comment: вероятно в @Target должно быть ElementType.METHOD

Comment: аннотация стоит у класса. За класс вроде как отвечает `ElementType.TYPE`. И нет, не помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим, есть такой класс:

```
@MyAnno("vvv")
public class Anno
{
    @MyAnno("xxx")
    public final int x = 0;
}
```

Тестовый код для получения аннотации этого класса:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Object object = new Anno();
    Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields)
    {
        MyAnno myAnno = field.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class);
        System.out.println("Field value: " + myAnno.value());
    }
    MyAnno myAnno = clazz.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class);
    System.out.println("Class value: " + myAnno.value());
}
```

На экран выводится:

```
Field value: xxx
Class value: vvv
```

Если использовать

```
Class clazz = object.getClass();
```

то придётся явно приводить тип:

```
MyAnno myAnno = (MyAnno)clazz.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class);
```

Потому что при использовании raw-type (`Class`) происходит стирание generic-типов в методах, из-за чего метод `getAnnotation` начинает возвращать просто `Annotation`.